# Type of member variables in a const member function

Tags: c++, constants, type-deduction

When I have a member function marked as const and inspect the types of the member variables I get some results I don't expect.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template<typename T>
struct type_printer;

class const_type_test {
public:
    void test() const {
        type_printer<decltype(value)> _;
    }
    int& test2() const {
        return value;
    }
    void test3() const {
        auto& x = value;
        type_printer<decltype(x)> _;
    }
    void test4() const {
        auto* x = &value;
        type_printer<decltype(*x)> _;
    }
private:
    int value;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    const const_type_test x;

    return 0;
}
```

My understanding is that when you are in a const method the method is effectively some name mangled name then they parameter type is classname const* const. I always thought that in the const method scope the member variables are effectively const, i.e. value would be const int. However when using the compiler error to deduce the types I get types I don't expect.

The error output for `void const_type_test::test() const`: aggregate `type_printer<int> _` has incomplete type and cannot be defined, `type_printer<decltype(value)> _;`

So I am seeing the type was deduced as int. I thought it would be const int as you can not change the value. Am I using decltype wrong? Or have I a hole in my understanding.

The reason I guess for asking is that in `test2` the compiler complains: binding reference of type `int&` to `const int` discards qualifiers. Which is exactly what I expect. Can bind a const reference to non const reference.

Example 3 shows the following error: error: aggregate `type_printer<const int&> _` has incomplete type and cannot be defined `type_printer<decltype(x)> _`. Which is what I expect it has been deduced as a const reference.

Example 4: deduces also a `type_printer<const int&>` which I thought would be a pointer.

Keen to get some reference to the standard to find out where the holes in my knowledge are. I am also wondering if there are some weird type deduction rules when using `decltype` that are tripping me up.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`decltype` has special rule for class members. It returns the actual type of the member. If you want `decltype` to consider the context (inside a const function), then you can wrap the expression inside parentheses.

**Without Paranthesis:**

```
 void test() const {
        type_printer<decltype(value)> _;
    }
```

```
c.cpp:10:39: error: implicit instantiation of undefined template 'type_printer<int>'
        type_printer<decltype(value)> _;
```

**With Paranthesis:**

```
 void test() const {
        type_printer<decltype((value))> _;
    }
```

```
c.cpp:10:41: error: implicit instantiation of undefined template 'type_printer<const int &>'
        type_printer<decltype((value))> _;
```

Reference:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype

> If the argument is an unparenthesized id-expression or **an unparenthesized class member access expression**, then decltype yields the type of the entity named by this expression. If there is no such entity, or if the argument names a set of overloaded functions, the program is ill-formed.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/decltype-cpp?view=vs-2019

> If the expression parameter is an identifier or **a class member access**, decltype(expression) is the type of the entity named by expression. If there is no such entity or the expression parameter names a set of overloaded functions, the compiler yields an error message.

Comment: This special rule works for regular variables as well.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat out of curiosity, could you provide an example for a regular variable where the double parenthesis will yield a different result?

Comment: @Oersted Any variable that isn't an lvalue reference will give you a different result (`decltype((var))` will always give you lvalue references, since all variables are lvalues.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the right type. Some types have lower ranges than others